# lxml Create XML fragment with no root element?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Is it possible using lxml (or the builtin etree library) to create an object that represents a fragment of xml, but contains two (or more) disjoint trees (i.e. each tree has its own separate root, but they share no common ancestor)?

That is, is there anything that could represent the following without creating another element to hold both of them:

```
<tree id="A"><anotherelement/></tree>
<tree id="B"><yetanotherelement/></tree>
```

I can't see anything in the lxml documentation that would allow that, and stackoverflow seems not to have anything directly on point.

**The use-case here is that I am generating xml programmatically, and the fragments will be assembled into one document for output. I'd like an object I don't need to iterate over/special case, just pass to the lxml methods as if it were a proper tree.**

(I am aware that such fragments would not of themselves be a complete and correct xml document; I want to store the intermediate products before assembly into such a document).

Comment: What about just making a list of lxml objects?  That's pretty much what you have...

Comment: @larsks Right, but then I need to write code that handles the presence of a list, rather than passing an object of the type the xml API expects. That also entails either special-casing in my code, or always holding a list. That is why it would be preferable.

Answer (score 6):

yes, there is such a functionality in the `lxml.html` package, it's called `fragment_fromstring` or `fragments_fromstring`, but in most cases the html parser also handles xml quite well:

```
from lxml import etree, html

xml = """
    <tree id="A"><anotherelement/></tree>
    <tree id="B"><yetanotherelement/></tree>
"""

fragments = html.fragments_fromstring(xml)

root = etree.Element("root")
for f in fragments:
    root.append(f)

print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

output:

```
<root>
  <tree id="A">
    <anotherelement/>
  </tree>
  <tree id="B">
    <yetanotherelement/>
  </tree>
</root>
```

if you look at [what's going on under the hood](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/901c891b37e9bc54834d0ba2396d33612e08b85f/src/lxml/html/__init__.py#L538), it probably wouldn't be too difficult to do the same using the xml parser if you're not happy with the other result.

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually want to create the fragment programmatically, so I will peek under the hood.

Comment: Ah, it still returns a list - I was hoping that there would be a way to create an object that I don't need to iterate over/special case, just pass to the lxml methods as if it were a proper tree. I'll accept this answer in the next couple of days, assuming no-one else knows of some magic method.

Comment: +1 but definitely important to know that `fragments_fromstring()` returns a list and `fragment_fromstring()` will only except a single element

Comment: Note that `html.fragments_fromstring` will not preserve the case of tag names (it converts them all to lower case), whereas `lxml.fromstring` will.